# how can I populate a SelectList from this Linq query?

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities

I am wanting to return the results of this query into something I can use to populate a SelectList.  I tried a NameValueCollection, and an IEnumerable, but both failed.

What are my options given this code?  This code does not work, but the query is exactly what I want.

```
        public IEnumerable GetValidAssociationsForSelectList()
        {
            var associations = (from a in context.Associations
                               join u in context.Units on a.AssociationKey equals u.AssociationKey
                               where a.CCRRecording != null && a.CCRRecording.ToString() != ""
                               orderby a.LegalName
                                select new { a.AssociationKey, LegalName = a.LegalName.Replace("'", "") }).Distinct();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return associations in your query:

```
public IEnumerable GetValidAssociationsForSelectList() {

    var associations = ( .... )

    return associations;

}
```

And then iterate through the IENumerable to populate the ListItems in the DropDownList, something like this:

```
foreach (var item in GetValidAssociationsForSelectList())
{
    ddlAssociations.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.AssociationKey, item.LegalName));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the return type of your `select` statement match your IEnumerable.

Here's one way to go about it:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> GetValidAssociationsForSelectList() {
    var associations = ...;
    return associations.Select(a => new ListItem(item.AssociationKey, item.LegalName));
}
```